# How to make items from an array to show on another component when i click the buy button?

Tags: node.js, arrays, angular, typescript

```
import { Item } from './item';

export const ITEMS: Item[] = [
 { id: 21, name: "Halatul Betivan", type: "armura", intelligence: 2, agility: 4, attackpower: 1},
 { id: 22, name: "Tricou Gucci", type: "armura", intelligence: 5, agility: 2, attackpower: 4},
 { id: 23, name: "Pantofi Mike", type:"cizme", intelligence: 2, agility: 4, attackpower: 3},
 { id: 24, name: "Louis Vuitton", type: "casca", intelligence: 4, agility: 4, attackpower: 3},
 { id: 25, name: "Staniol", type: "armura", intelligence: 7, agility: 2, attackpower: 5},
 { id: 26, name: "Versace", type: "armura", intelligence: 2, agility: 4, attackpower: 3},
 { id: 27, name: "Air Force 1", type: "cizme", intelligence: 4, agility: 4, attackpower: 1},
 { id: 28, name: "Jordan", type: "casca", intelligence: 1, agility: 4, attackpower: 6},
 { id: 29, name: "New York", type: "casca", intelligence: 1, agility: 6, attackpower: 4},
 { id: 20, name: "Geaca Piele", type: "armura", intelligence: 2, agility: 8, attackpower: 1},
 { id: 31, name: "Ciocate", type: "cizme", intelligence: 2, agility: 4, attackpower: 3},
 { id: 32, name: "Sandale Crocs", type: "cizme", intelligence: 4, agility: 6, attackpower: 4},
 { id: 33, name: "Tricou Negru", type: "armura", intelligence: 2, agility: 3, attackpower: 3},
 { id: 34, name: "Pantofi Lacoste", type: "cizme", intelligence: 2, agility: 2, attackpower: 6},
 { id: 35, name: "Palarie Gangster", type: "casca", intelligence: 4, agility: 4, attackpower: 3},
 { id: 36, name: "Sapca FCSB", type: "casca", intelligence: 6, agility: 3, attackpower: 3},
 { id: 37, name: "Tricou FCSB", type: "armura", intelligence: 2, agility: 6, attackpower: 3},
 { id: 38, name: "Adidas Editie Limitata FCSB", type: "cizme", intelligence: 4, agility: 2, attackpower: 1},

]
```

```
<h2>Items shop</h2>
<mat-selection-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items"
    [class.selected]="item === selectedItem"
    (click)="onSelect(item)">
    <span class="mat-badge"></span> {{item.name}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-selection-list>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<div *ngIf="selectedItem">

  <h2>Detalii: {{selectedItem.name | uppercase}}</h2>

  <div><span>id: </span>{{selectedItem.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div><span>intelligence: {{selectedItem.intelligence}}</span></div>
  <div><span>agility: {{selectedItem.agility}}</span></div>
  <div><span>attackpower: {{selectedItem.attackpower}}</span></div>
<button  mat-fab>Buy</button>
```

Got this code to show the items but i dunno how to add them to another component

How do i make an item from this array to add to another inventory component when clicking buy?
I'm kinda new to this but i am struggling for too many hours to find a solve to this issue.

Comment: Are you using the another component in this same file?

Comment: yep, i want to buy a character or item from that array and add it to the inventory component

Comment: I have given the solution below. Please refer it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So you just have to maintain the list of the items for which the user have clicked buy button.

So in .ts file declare the new variable named **buyedItems**. And add the method to add items.

```
public buyedItems:any[]=[];

addItems(item){
 this.buyedItems.push(item)
}
```

Now in html add the following line for using the inventory component.
Assuming your component tag is

```
<app-inventory [buyedItems]=buyedItems></app-inventory>
```

And update your html with the below code:

```
<h2>Items shop</h2>
<mat-selection-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items"
    [class.selected]="item === selectedItem"
    (click)="onSelect(item)">
    <span class="mat-badge"></span> {{item.name}}
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-selection-list>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>
<div *ngIf="selectedItem">

  <h2>Detalii: {{selectedItem.name | uppercase}}</h2>

  <div><span>id: </span>{{selectedItem.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="selectedItem.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div><span>intelligence: {{selectedItem.intelligence}}</span></div>
  <div><span>agility: {{selectedItem.agility}}</span></div>
  <div><span>attackpower: {{selectedItem.attackpower}}</span></div>
<button  mat-fab (click)="addItem(selectedItem)">Buy</button>
```

And in the inventory component take the @Input as **buyedItems**.

Comment: What is the error? Please show me what you have tried.

Comment: the button does nothing

Comment: you just have to add click event to the button.

Comment: Can u tell me again where should i put the method and the buyedItems?

Comment: In your .ts file of the same component. You can just share stackbliz by adding your code to it.

Comment: I hope you are able to resolve the problem. Please upvote too so that it can be useful to others as well.